# Why can't I send a ( to SendKeys in JScript?

Tags: javascript, windows-7, jscript, wsh, sendkeys

Why when I send a `(` to `WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys()` in Microsoft JScript do I get the following error?

```
C:\js\test.js(7, 9) Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument
```

I've tried escaping it, googling it etc...and it still gives me the error.

I am running it with `cscript.exe`

```
(function () {

var WshSh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");

WshSh.SendKeys("(");
})();
```

Comment: Ah ok Thanks. Well I know nothing about what that thing does but the error sure would make me suspect that the "shell" parser takes the string delivered by that `.SendKeys()` thing to be a complete expression (of some sort) to be parsed.

Comment: I figured it out.  You have to wrap the character in `{` and `}` when it's passed.

Comment: I would never have guessed that in a million years :)